# insertion sort is skipping last element

Tags: python, for-loop, insertion-sort

This insertion sort mis sorting all elements but the last. It's very weird bc I have an identical function that sorts ALL elements by a different attribute. I tried copying, pasting, and altering the working func, but that seemed futile.

```
for i in range(1, len(metals)):
   index = i
   while index != 0 and metals[index].weightPerBar > metals[index - 1].weightPerBar:
       metals[index], metals[index - 1] = metals[index - 1], metals[index]
       index -= 1
```

Thanks

Heres the rest of module:

```
    class Metal(struct):
        """
        Represents a single metal type, composed of:
        :slot name (str): The name of the metal
        :slot totalBars (int): The total number of bars
        :slot weightPerBar (int): The weight of a single bar
        :slot valuePerBar (int): The value of a single bar
        :slot valuePerWeight (float): The value per weight of the metal
        :slot barsTaken (int): The number of bars added to the satchel
        """
        _slots = ((str, "name"), (int, "totalBars"), (int, "weightPerBar"), (int, "valuePerBar"), (float, "valuePerWeight"), (int, "barsTaken"))

        pass


    def createMetal(name, totalBars, weightPerBar, valuePerBar):
        """
        Create and return a new Metal object.
        :param name (str): The name of the metal
        :param totalBars (int): The total number of bars
        :param weightPerBar (int): The weight of a single bar
        :param valuePerBar (int): The value of a single bar
        :return: A newly initialized Metal object
        :rtype: Metal
        """

        new_metal = Metal(name, totalBars, weightPerBar, valuePerBar)
        return new_metal

        pass

    def readMetals(fileName):
        """
        Read the metals from a file whose format is:
            metalName totalBars weightPerBar valuePerBar
        :param fileName (str): The name of the file
        :return: A list of Metal objects
        :rtype: list
        """
        metal_list = []
        file = open(fileName)
        for line in file:
            line = line.split()
            weight_per_bar = float(line[3])/float(line[2]) # creating derived value
            new_metal = Metal(line[0], int(line[1]), int(line[2]), int(line[3]), weight_per_bar, 0)

            metal_list += [new_metal]
        return metal_list

        pass


    def sortMetalsByValuePerBar(metals):
        """
        Sort the metals by value per bar using insertion sort.  The list of
        metals is modified in place to be ordered by value per bar.
        :param metals (list of Metal): The list of metals
        :return: None
        :rtype: NoneType
        """

        for i in range(1, len(metals)):
            index = i
            while index != 0 and metals[index].valuePerBar > metals[index - 1].valuePerBar:
                metals[index], metals[index - 1] = metals[index - 1], metals[index]
                index -= 1


        pass

    def sortMetalsByValuePerWeight(metals):
        """
        Sort the metals by value per weight using insertion sort.  The list of
        metals is modified in place to be ordered by value per weight.
        :param metals (list of Metal): The list of metals
        :return: None
        :rtype: NoneType
        """
        for i in range(1, len(metals)):
            index = i
            while index != 0 and metals[index].weightPerBar > metals[index - 1].weightPerBar:
                metals[index], metals[index - 1] = metals[index - 1], metals[index]
                index -= 1
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work if .weightPerBar are all of the same type and are numeric (not strings or other objects). If weight is a string, it could have the situation where "2", "6", "4", "10" sorts as "6", "4", "2", "10". Instead of 10, 6, 4, 2 as desired.

Comment: i forced the class to cast as ints

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my machine, but why are you implementing a sorting algorithm on your own? You can just use:

metals.sort(key=lambda metal: metal.weightPerBar, reverse=True)

Comment: When it sorts [150, 400, 125, 166] as  [166, 150, 125, 400]

Comment: weight_per_bar = int(line[3])/int(line[2]) # creating derived value
        new_metal = Metal(line[0], int(line[1]), int(line[2]), int(line[3]), float(weight_per_bar), 0)

Comment: Still, you haven't given me enough of the code to identify where your problem is. Nevertheless, your code is a flawless implementation of insertion sort when I replace metals[index].weightPerBar with metals[index] and metals[index - 1].weightPerBar with metals[index - 1], and take metals to be an array or integers. This means your problem must lie elsewhere, and I can't solve it without getting more of the code.

Comment: I had a little less reputation than what's needed to comment on his original post, but I wanted to help him. Anyway, I edited my answer so it's helpful now, even though I still don't know where the original code is wrong.